how should i put my chrome driver path porperly?
I'm trying to make an web automated scraper, and I want to fetch data from websites for my data model. I'm using the following code to set up my webdriver:
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/dell/Downloads/chrome-win64')

But I'm getting this error shown below:
PS C:\Users\dell\Desktop\first> & c:/Users/dell/Desktop/first/.venv/Scripts/python.exe c:/Users/dell/Desktop/first/second.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\dell\Desktop\first\second.py", line 6, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/dell/Downloads/chrome-win64')
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\first\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\first\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 50, in __init__
    if finder.get_browser_path():
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\first\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 47, in get_browser_path 
    return self._binary_paths()["browser_path"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\first\.venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 56, in _binary_paths    
    browser = self._options.capabilities["browserName"]
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'

How can I fix this?

The webdriver.Chrome builder doesn't require any arguments. Just take out the file path and your program should work fine. If you need to pass more information, use the options argument, not a string.
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome()


do you have the corresponding version of ChromeDriver installed? You can try adding ChromeDriver to the environment variable. Generally, ChromeDriver is under the Chrome installation path.Then use Chrome's "standard location" in the following ways:
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd

options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options)

